# Lua: Can I use colon syntax here?

Tags: lua

I'm running this function a lot which shortens the name of a string:

```
function shorten(st)
  return string.sub(st,6)
end

function test(input)
  local h = shorten(input)
  print(""..h)
end

test("helloworld")
```

I want to write it with a colon like the other functions in this context, which all go like *world():context():manager()*, not manager(context(world())).
I read that using the syntax with the colon passes the first as an argument into the latter, but this does not work:

```
function shorten(st)
  return string.sub(st,6)
end

function test(input)
  local h = input:shorten()
  print(""..h)
end

test("helloworld")
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if it is ok that `:shorten()` can be used on every string in your program that's probably fine. just add it to the string library as shown in the answer below. I personally would simply use `:sub(6)` so I don't have to think about what `:shorten()` actually does. but if shortenning to 6 characters is what you always do, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

depending on your flavor of lua, you can simply define shorten as `string.shorten`

This works because the metatable for all strings references the string library. That is why adding a function to `string` will add make it accessible to any defined strings.

```lua
function string.shorten(st)
  return string.sub(st,6)
end

function test(input)
  local h = input:shorten()
  print(h)
end

test("helloworld")
```

Output:

> world

---

Your example of colon syntax is not exactly how it works. It is syntactic sugar

```
someClassInstance:method("arg")
```

is equivalent to

```
someClassInstance.method(someClassInstance, "arg")
```

You often see colon syntax used to improve readability of OO style lua, and is described here in [Programing in Lua: 16 – Object-Oriented Programming](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)

---

side note: you did `print(""..h)` which seems weird since it is functionally identical to just doing `print(h)` but is more expensive.

Comment: "This works because the metatable for strings is the string table. "  no. `string` refers to  Lua's string library. So does the `__index` field of the metatable all strings have in common. that's two different tables.

Comment: @Piglet fair point I did over simplify that. does this sound better? "This works because the metatable for all strings references the string library."

Comment: kind of :-)  picky Germans...